# erorr on platformIO ide

Tags: arduino-uno, platformio

Hello everyone I wrote the following code in platformIO IDE to read a value from the YL-69 module and display it in 7segment, but I got this error:
error: no 'void SevenSegmentFun::bouncingBall(uint16_t, uint16_t, bool)' member function declared in class 'SevenSegmentFun'

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "SevenSegmentTM1637.h"


const byte PIN_CLK = 2;   // define CLK pin (any digital pin)
const byte PIN_DIO = 3;   // define DIO pin (any digital pin)
SevenSegmentTM1637    display(PIN_CLK, PIN_DIO);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);         
  display.begin();            
  display.setBacklight(100);  
  display.print("INIT");      
  delay(1000);   
  display.clear();
  // wait 1000 ms
  pinMode(A0,INPUT);
};

// run loop (forever)
void loop() {
   int i=analogRead(A0);
  display.print(i);
  delay(1000);
};
```

What is wrong? and How can i fix it?

Comment: Where is `SevenSegmentTM1637.h` from? Does it declare such a function? How?

Comment: Well, the function `bouncingBall` is not in the code snippet you posted. I doubt people will be able to help you based on what you provided. I would suggest you try to figure out where the class `SevenSegmentFun` is and where the function `bouncingBall` is called from. I would guess that either the function is not defined in the class, or it has a different signature that what is called, or there might be a typo in the call.